# Positioning in CSS: Center align a text inside child DIV which is already horizontally & vertically aligned inside parent DIV

Tags: html, css, position, center, vertical-alignment

I have an ***inner*** (child) **div** inside an ***outer*** (parent) **div**.

Inner div is both horizontally as well as vertically center aligned inside the outer div. Used **table-cell** & **vertical-align: middle** on parent element and **display: inline-block** in child element.

> I want to center align the text inside the inner div both horizontally as
>   well as vertically.

This question may seem to be duplicate, but it is not. The solutions provided on other links are usually based on -

1. **line-height**: which I feel is not a good solution because it depends on the parent's height.
2. **display: table-cell**: Inner element is already an *inline-block* in my solution, can't keep another **display** property on the same block.
3. **Flex**: is something which I am not aware of, hence accepted the solution posted by @xenio-gracias.

How to achieve this?

Here's my current working code:

```css
/* Lesson 3 (PART 1): div inside div */
.outer-lesson3 {
 border: 1px solid lightcoral;
 display: table-cell;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}

.inner-lesson3 {
 border: 1px solid mediumseagreen;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 150px; 
}
/* Lesson 3 (PART 1) ENDS */
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prac.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Lesson 3 -->
    <div class="outer-lesson3">
        <div class="inner-lesson3">
            Horizontally & Vertically Center 'div' inside 'div'
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @paulie-d, this is not duplicate. The solutions given at the mentioned linked are not going to work for my scenario. Even if I want them to work, I will have to change my solution which is entirely a different scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used `flexbox` to achieve it Hope this helps. thanks

```css
/* Lesson 3 (PART 1): div inside div */

.outer-lesson3 {
  border: 1px solid lightcoral;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner-lesson3 {
  border: 1px solid mediumseagreen;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Lesson 3 (PART 1) ENDS */
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="prac.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Lesson 3 -->
  <div class="outer-lesson3">
    <div class="inner-lesson3">
      Horizontally & Vertically Center 'div' inside 'div'
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```